# postgresql-sort array by words in each elements

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

There is string array

`ARRAY['CAT','CAT DOG CAT','DOG Cat']`

Now  i want to sort this array on count of words in each element. I have tried but cannot get any success.

I want this output

`ARRAY['CAT DOG CAT','DOG CAT','Cat']`

How i can do this?

Comment: Where does `'Cat'` cat come from in the output. There is no such element in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does feel rather clumsy, but I can't think of a simpler solution right now:

```
with val (col) as (
  values (ARRAY['CAT','CAT DOG CAT','DOG Cat'])
), word_list as (
  select unnest(col) as pc
  from val
), wc as (
  select array_length(string_to_array(pc, ' '),1) as word_count, pc
  from word_list
)
select array_agg(pc order by word_count desc)
from wc;
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an alternative:

```
select array_agg(a) 
from (
  select unnest(array['CAT','CAT DOG CAT','DOG Cat']) as a 
  order by a) s
```