# SQL - Sort specific column based on another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data in following form, I wanted to sort the `usernames` column based on specfic `user_id` that I have to found from `user_ids` array.

```
 usernames     | empno    |   user_ids |       
------------------+---------------------
{ Akon, Den }  |    11    | { 12, 13 } |
{ John, Nash } |     7    | { 15, 12 } |
{ Ahmad, Umar }|     9    | { 18, 12 } |
```

Forexample, usernames with `user_id` = 12 should be shown first. Result would look like as below

```
 usernames     | empno    |       
------------------+--------
{ Akon, Den }  |    11    |
{ Nash, John } |     7    |
{ Umar, Ahmad }|     9    |
```

I am sure there would be some easiest way of doing this in Postgres. This structure is just an example.

Comment: why does a user_id map to multiple user_names?

Comment: Comma separated data isn't the SQL way, that design will only cause you lots of trouble... (And make easy things very difficult.)

Comment: @jarlh It is according to my database architecture I have to export some information in CSV because of have to do something like this.

Comment: @vkp according my architecture I can map one user_id to multiple usernames :)

Comment: This simply means you have your map wrong. You either need to change the direction of your references or use an additional table. Can you provide the structure of relevant tables, please? What is `user_ids` supposed to reference?

Comment: Even if the business rule allows multiple user names for each user_id your db design is very poor. Search for database normalization.

Comment: Why is `Umar Ahma` sorted _after_  `John, Nash`?  Both have `user_id = 12` - what is the criteria to sort one before the other?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in fact, the order must be applied IN the first column ({John, Nash} becomes {Nash, John}). The rows order doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Then this seems a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24987547/330315 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913368/sorting-array-elements or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991423/postgresql-sort-array-by-words-in-each-elements or similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+sort+array

Answer (score 1):

Well, the biggest issue here is that you are working with arrays, actually making things more difficult. If you really don't have normalized data in your database, you can use [`unnest` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) to make it row-by-row and array_agg to get the arrays back. If you are on 9.4+ it is easy as:

```
SELECT
    t.empno,
    array_agg(u.username ORDER BY u.user_id) AS username_agg,
    array_agg(u.user_id ORDER BY u.user_id) AS user_id_agg
FROM
    your_table t,
    unnest(t.usernames, t.user_ids) AS u(username, user_id)
GROUP BY
    t.empno
ORDER BY
    user_ids_agg
```

Before 9.4 you don't have LATERAL queries nor `unnest` with many parameters, so it would be a bit harder:

```
SELECT
    t.empno,
    array_agg(t.username ORDER BY t.user_id) AS username_agg,
    array_agg(t.user_id ORDER BY t.user_id) AS user_id_agg
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t1.empno,
            unnest(t1.usernames) AS username,
            unnest(t1.user_ids) AS user_id
        FROM
            your_table t1
    ) t
GROUP BY
    t.empno
ORDER BY
    user_ids_agg
```

Both solutions assume that you have the same number of elements in both arrays for each row.

Please let me know if the code doesn't run (I haven't actually tried, so there may have been a typo or logic issue).

Answer (score 0):

@MuhamamdAwais if you will only sort over the first element of the `user_ids`,
try this: `select usernames,empno from your_table order by user_ids[1]`